# Excel name first 30 rows "Group 1", next 30 rows "Group 2"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of 30,000 or so rows. I have a column called "Groups". The first 30 rows, I want to name "Group 1" and have that value in the "Groups" column. The next 30 rows would be named "Group 2" and that value would live in the Groups column, etc. until the list is over.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the following formula: `="GROUP " & ROUNDUP(ROW()/30,0)`

Comment: Please post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
="GROUP " & ROUNDUP(ROW()/30,0)
```